# Unable to send a post form in Java

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection

The objective of the code is to insert the parameters into the form then submits the form which in turn enters the data into a MySQL database. The problem is that the method doesn't post the data. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I've looked at so many questions regarding this but nothing seems to work.

Here is the form.

```
<form action="http://localhost/Documents/dataadded.php" method="post">

<b>Add a New Data</b>

<p>Email Address:
<input type="text" name="email_address" size="30" value="" />
</p>

<p>Email Pass:
<input type="text" name="email_pass" size="30" value="" />
</p>

<p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</p>

</form>
```

Here is the Java code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    String key1 = "email_address";
    String key2 = "email_pass";
    String key3 = "submit";

    String param1 = "testemail@gmail.com";
    String param2 = "password123";
    String param3 = "Send";
    try {
        URL website = new URL("http://localhost/Documents/added.php");

        Map<String,String> arguments = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        arguments.put(key1, param1);
        arguments.put(key2, param2);
        arguments.put(key3, param3);

        StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner("&");
        for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : arguments.entrySet())
            sj.add(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8") + "=" 
                 + URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        byte[] out = sj.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        int length = out.length;

        HttpURLConnection connection =  (HttpURLConnection) website.openConnection(); 
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(length);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.getOutputStream().write(out);


        System.out.println(sj.toString());

        InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(response);
        String responsebody = scan.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        System.out.println(responsebody);



    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

If anyone could shed some light on what's wrong with the code, it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is PHP involved?

Comment: When the form is submitted, the data is passed to http://localhost/Documents/dataadded.php which has PHP code which handles the data and adds it to the database.

Comment: @C.Trant But is that actually related to your question? How you handle the data seems irrelevant, your problem is passing of the data

Comment: The URL in the Java code is different from the one in the form.

Comment: Yeah my bad, first post I made and it suggested the php tag along with the others so I clicked them.

Comment: @C.Trant Does Lothar's comment fix your problem?

Comment: It's supposed to be different, the URL in the form is the URL which you are taken to after submit has been pressed.

Comment: No, unfortunately not

Comment: Flushing the stream is common practice and very useful if you want to make sure that the data is actually sent.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either, thanks though

Comment: @Lothar I just tried what you said and it worked! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: How is MySQL involved?

Answer (score 0):

You have to flush the OutputStream before you can open the InputStream.  Below is the method I created to do POST requests.

```
private String doPost(String urlString, LinkedHashMap<String, String> params) throws Exception {
    //...make the content
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
    //...append params
    boolean first = true;
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
        if (!first) {
            content.append("&");
        } else {
            first = false;
        }
        content.append(entry.getKey()).append("=").append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), charset));
    }
    //... send POST request
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection con;
    con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setUseCaches(false);
    try (OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream(), charset)) {
        writer.write(content.toString());
        writer.flush();
    }
    //...get response
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(con.getInputStream(), charset)) {
        String resp = s.useDelimiter("\\A").hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
        return resp;
    }
}
```

Comment: The try-with-resources closes the output stream, and closing the output stream flushes it, and you certainly shouldn't flush inside loops..

Comment: Your answer states that you have to flush. You don't.

Comment: @EJP what loop are you talkign about?  i admit that close does flush, but a flush needs to happen, the question is whether or not you want it to be done for you via the close or if you want to be explicit about it.  I chose to be explicit about it.